# How to aggr. daily sales orders into monthly totals and have it as datetime format (e.g. January 2015) in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, parsing, aggregate

I have a pandas dataframe with 3 columns:

- OrderID_new (integer)
- OrderTotal  (float)
- OrderDate_new (string or datetime sometimes)

Sales order ID's are in the first column, order values (totals) are in the 2nd column and order date - in mm/dd/yyyy format are in the last column.

I need to do 2 things:

1. to aggregate the order totals:
   a) first into total sales per each day and then
   b) into total sales per each calendar month
2. to convert values in OrderDate_new from mm/dd/yyyy format (e.g. 01/30/2015) into MM YYYY (e.g. January 2015) format.

The problem is some input files have 3rd column (date) already in datetime format while some have it as string format so that means sometimes string to datetime parsing will be needed while in other cases, reformatting datetime.

I have been trying to do 2 step aggregation with groupby but I'm getting some strange daily and monthly totals that make no sense.

What I need as the final stage is time series with 2 columns - 1. monthly sales and 2. month (Month Year)...

Then I will need to select and train some model for monthly sales time series forecast (out of scope for this question)...

What am I doing wrong?
How to do it effectively in Python?

dataframe example:

[image: dataframe example]

Comment: Think [mre] - can you show some code, where you're stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide usable sample data,  hence I've synthesized.

1. `resample()` allows you to rollup a date column.  Have provided daily and monthly
2. `pd.to_datetime()` gives you what you want

```
def mydf(size=10):
    return pd.DataFrame({"OrderID_new":np.random.randint(100,200, size),
    "OrderTotal":np.random.randint(200, 10000, size),
    "OrderDate_new":np.random.choice(pd.date_range(dt.date(2019,8,1),dt.date(2020,1,1)),size)})

# smash orderdate to be a string for some rows
df = pd.concat([mydf(5), mydf(5).assign(OrderDate_new=lambda dfa: dfa.OrderDate_new.dt.strftime("%Y/%m/%d"))])
# make sure everything is a date..
df.OrderDate_new = pd.to_datetime(df.OrderDate_new)

#  totals
df.resample("1d", on="OrderDate_new")["OrderTotal"].sum()
df.resample("1m", on="OrderDate_new")["OrderTotal"].sum()
```